# Monit config param - group?

Tags: linux, monit

I cannot locate information on the purpose of the group parameter below.
It appears in the documentation as a way to control access to a block, but I can't locate what it does in the following block.

```
# nginx check:
check process nginx with pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
  if cpu > 50% for 2 cycles then alert
  group www-data
```

Also, in some examples for monit, you'll see an explicit fail condition w/a then restart command. My understanding is the above block handles this for us automatically in the event of a failure. Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Groups are useful for the html GUI interface for Monit and M/Monit. You can use them on the commandline, for example:

> monit -g  stop

Will stop all processes with that groupname.

The "depends on" command might do what you are thinking of, for example:

> ```
> check process postfix with pidfile /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
>    start program = "/etc/init.d/postfix start"
>    stop  program = "/etc/init.d/postfix stop"
>    depends on postfix_bin
>         
> check file postfix_bin with path /usr/sbin/postfix
>    if failed permission 0755 then unmonitor
> ```

If postfix has wrong permissions (or isn't installed) it will not try to start it

Your example above will raise an alert. You need to replace the "alert" with "restart" in order to activate the response of running the stop then start programs automatically on process failure. If you remove the if statement entirely monit will default to doing a restart on failure.